# How do I mock an array in Rhino mocks

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino mocks and now I need to mock an array IFindUseCase[]

```
var findUseCases = mocks.StrictMock<IFindUseCase[]>();
```

But how do I use Expect.Call?

I thought it would be this, but may be not....!

```
Expect.Call(() => findUseCases[0].Process(null)).Return(null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to mock an actual Array in the first place? Just create a normal array of mocks.

Comment: Also use `mock.Expect(x => x.Process())` syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want to be creating a mock array, I think you want to create an array of mocks.

```
var case1 = mocks.StrictMock<IFindUseCase>();
var findUseCases = new IFindUseCase[]
     {
         case1
     };
```

And setup your expectation:

```
case1.Expect(m => m.Process(null)).Return(null);
```